# Gmail replacing img with span in html email

Tags: html, email, gmail, image

I'm trying to give a client a HTML email template so that they can just edit text. However when i send them the template in Gmail. The images will just show as "logo.jpg" for example.

I view the source and it's replaced the `<img>` tag with `<span>logo.jpg</span>`

This is the HTML i wrote:

```
<img width='200' src='http://www.example.co.uk/images/logo.JPG'></img>
```

Anything wrong with this? Is this across all email clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Images don't have closing  tags.

```
<img width='200' src='http://www.example.co.uk/images/logo.JPG' />
```